Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader create multiple sheet in php
i want to create multiple sheet excel file use library Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader.
i use this syntax :
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls",false); $data->val($row,$col,$sheet_index)   

but above syntax just for one sheet.
how to i make multiple sheet?
maybe anyone can make multiple sheet with library Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader

The reader just can read. You need to use the writer.
